# How to handle date/times in POST parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

By default, Rails' `config.time_zone` is UTC. So, fields like `created_at`, `updated_at` are saved in UTC.

Now, presume user's time zone is Pacific Standard Time (PST).

In order to show dates and times in the user's time zone, I have set `Time.zone` to PST.

Now, when a user enters a date (in user's local time zone, which is PST) in a form, that date is received in the controller according to the setting of `Time.zone`.

But, I want to save all times in the database in UTC.

So, how would I go about converting any date/time field in-place in the parameters hash to UTC? I'm wondering if there is a solution where Rails can do the conversion automatically?

I would like that any date/time received for any datetime field be converted to UTC, without having to write the conversion code in every controller.

#### UPDATE

I tested by setting Time.zone to `Pacific Time (US & Canada)` as well as to `Eastern Time (US & Canada)` and then saving a model. The `created_at` time in both cases was in `UTC`. So that confirms that setting `Time.zone` has no effect on what time is saved by Rails in the `created_at` field. That value is effected only by the `config.time_zone` (which if not defined in `application.rb` will default to UTC)

I'm so confused by this all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database, all dates are always saved as UTC. The config.time_zone parameter is setting the default value for Time.zone, just for display. So you don't have to do anything to get the behavior you desire, just keep Time.zone set correctly for the user, and rails takes care of the rest.

Comment: According to what I have tested, that does not seem true. Please see my question for update.

Comment: I don't think I follow, your update reiterates what I said: config.time_zone does not affect how the date is stored in the database, it is always stored as UTC. What it _does_ affect, is the default timezone used when retrieving a date through one of the models accessor methods. For example Model.created_at will be returned in the timezone specified by config.time_zone, unless you have set Time.zone to override it.

Comment: If you would like to convert from one timezone to another manually you can use the method: in_time_zone, like so: model.created_at.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm very confused about all the time-related stuff I've been doing :( I hate time zones!

Comment: Maybe you could also look at my (one more!) question on time zones?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073917/why-doesnt-config-time-zone-seem-to-do-anything