# Converting UTC time field from a POSTGRE/SQL database in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, utc, gmt

I am having a problem from my database.
I never been used to work in PostgreSQL, and i would like to make a select from a UTC datetime  field and getting a GMT Datetime as result.

Actually my request is : select dateheure from position
What should be the Postgresql request to do what i want to do ???

Thanks a lot
Gwenael

Answer (score 12):

PostgreSQL does have two [datetime types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html):

- `timestamp without time zone` (default implicit `timestamp`)
- `timestamp with time zone`

I guess that you have table with UTC datetime (without time zone type):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE datetimetest
(
    datetime timestamp
);

\d datetimetest
           Table "pg_temp_1.datetimetest"
  Column  |            Type             | Modifiers 
----------+-----------------------------+-----------
 datetime | timestamp without time zone | 

INSERT INTO datetimetest SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';

SELECT datetime FROM datetimetest;
          datetime          
----------------------------
 2011-08-15 15:04:06.507166
(1 row)
```

To get datetime in some timezone you could use [`AT TIME ZONE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
SELECT datetime AT TIME ZONE 'GMT-5' FROM datetimetest;
           timezone            
-------------------------------
 2011-08-15 10:04:06.507166+00
(1 row)
```

Comment: Just tried that : SELECT dateheure AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' FROM position;

Comment: and get that : ERREUR:  la fonction pg_catalog.timezone(unknown, text) n'existe pas
LINE 1: SELECT dateheure AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' FROM position;
                         ^
HINT:  Aucune fonction ne correspond au nom donné et aux types d'arguments.
Vous devez ajouter des conversions explicites de type.

Comment: @Gwenael: Your `dateheure` column has `text` type, so it's not recognized here. Probably all you need is explicit cast to timestamp, that is: `SELECT dateheure::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' FROM position;`. However to store date times probably you should use one of two timestamp types.

Answer (score 1):

[In a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151084/which-timestamp-type-to-choose-in-a-postgresql-database/6158432#6158432) I use a `CHECK()` constraint to make sure that you only store and receive `UTC` out of the database. Hopefully it's helpful.