# timestamp to use specific timezone?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The below is my table definition that automatically inserts timestamp value into each record. All i want to do is let the timestamp use a specific timezone for example in my case i want it to use the current time of British Columbia How do i do that ?

Because when i insert data in the table i do not really pass a timestame value from my php script but it takes the default value.

```
CREATE TABLE `cfv_postbusupdate` (
  `BusNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Direction` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'Not Provided',
  `StopNames` varchar(300) DEFAULT 'Not Provided',
  `Status` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'Not Provided',
  `comments` varchar(150) DEFAULT 'None',
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'anonymous_user',
  `dayofweek` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DatePosted` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps are stored as UTC values ad converted on retrieval to the time zone in use by the application. If you want British Columbia time set the time zone with `SET time_zone = 'america/vancouver';`

The manual reference is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: not sure i am doing it right but i opned phpmyadmin and in the sql SQL tab tried to run the following command SET time_zone = 'america/vancouver';  but got the following error #1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'america/vancouver' ?

Comment: The timezone strings won't work if you haven't installed them. If you're running on a hosted server your ISP would have to do it. You can use `set time_zone = '+08:00'` (or whatever your offset is), but that won't take account of daylight-saving time. Note that this setting applies on a per-connection basis. See the reference manual I linked to for a complete rundown.

Answer (score 0):

***use this one: refer this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/6158432/3242978***

```
-- Make sure we're all working off of the same local time zone
test=> SET timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
SET
test=> SELECT NOW();
              now              
-------------------------------
 2011-05-27 15:47:58.138995-07
(1 row)

test=> SELECT NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
          timezone          
----------------------------
 2011-05-27 22:48:02.235541
(1 row)
```

***update: 1***

According to [**MySQL docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_unknown_system_variable), the error `#1193` occurs when you use wrong code for `SQLSTATE`.

```
Message: Unknown system variable %s
```

And, as you can see on the [**same page**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html), the `SQLSTATE 99003` is not defined.

Comment: can i run this command using phpmyadmin ? I tried it but got an error saying #1193 - Unknown system variable 'timezone'