# Rails Date Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, parameters

I am learning rails and have recently come across a road block. Any guidance is appreciated.

I am using device and I have a `:confirmed_at` DateTime column as a protected attribute. So to update it from my admin interface I super the controller update method and add:

```
      @user.update_attribute(:confirmed_at, params[:user][:confirmed_at])
      @user.update_attribute(:school_id, params[:user][:school_id])
```

`:school_id` gets update correctly but `:confirmed_at`, which is datetime, is always nil. I looked at the params hash and sure enough it does not have `:confirmed_at` but it has

```
      "confirmed_at(1i)"=>"2012", 
      "confirmed_at(2i)"=>"6", 
      "confirmed_at(3i)"=>"2", 
      "confirmed_at(4i)"=>"04",   
      "confirmed_at(5i)"=>"11"
```

Rails doesn't seem to be translating the parameters for the fields into datetime objects for the database.

** How do I capture these value to update my `:confirmed_at` field properly?

Any help is appreciated.

Rails 3.1,
Ruby 1.9

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using `datetime_select` helper.

Check this out: [Where is the Rails method that converts data from `datetime_select` into a DateTime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073756/where-is-the-rails-method-that-converts-data-from-datetime-select-into-a-datet)

Comment: Thank you Alexey. I am not sure handling the conversion manually is appropriate though. Correct me if I am wrong but this seem to suggest I should get the params individually and manually?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@user.update_attribute(:confirmed_at, params[:confirmed_at])
```

The date_select is sent in its own params and not as part of the params[:user] hash.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Did not quite do it. An ugly solution so far is to add the fiels as a textfield and just type the date into as 12/12/12.

Comment: Thank you Anil. I thought this would work because it makes sense and I had not tried it before reading your comment.

Comment: @Yuri So what is your final solution?

Comment: I added a field as :string and just add the value in human format (12/12/12...) and it converts and save it fine. I don't like it but since is for the app Admin interface where only I really have access it is fine. Maybe I should put this in an answer.