# Rails - Comparing Datetime objects (date between two form dates)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, datetime

I've been struggling with an issue all day and can't figure it out. How do you compare two datetime variables in ruby/rails?

Controller

```
@events = Event.where('date > ? AND date < ?', params[:timeMin], params[:timeMax])
```

view: index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag events_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= datetime_select :timeMin, params[:timeMin] %>
    <%= datetime_select :timeMax, params[:timeMax] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search Near", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The Event model has an attribute 'date' which is a datetime object. I've tried converting the params[:timeMin] to a string, but them it makes it very difficult to compare times.

The overarching goal is to search for events that are happening between two times.

thanks

error - happens after search

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE (date > '---
- (1i)
- ''2014''
','---
- (2i)
- ''1''
','---
- (3i)
- ''8''
','---
- (4i)
- ''14''
','---
- (5i)
- ''36''
' AND date < '---
- (1i)
- ''2014''
','---
- (2i)
- ''1''
','---
- (3i)
- ''13''
','---
- (4i)
- ''14''
','---
- (5i)
- ''36''
') ORDER BY events.created_at DESC
```

Comment: it looks alright to me, could you post some of the actual errors/issues you had with the queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used datetime_select and it doesn't pass everything in one params[:timeMin], you first have to convert it into DateTime object like this

```
timemin = DateTime.new(params["timeMin(1i)"].to_i,
                       params["timeMin(2i)"].to_i,
                       params["timeMin(3i)"].to_i,
                       params["timeMin(4i)"].to_i,
                       params["timeMin(5i)"].to_i)
```

In the same way you need to convert :timeMax into DateTime object. Then you can compare both.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the params directly to SQL, so it doesn't understand. You need to create a DateTime object from the params. You can see how others have done it here:

[Where is the Rails method that converts data from `datetime_select` into a DateTime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073756/where-is-the-rails-method-that-converts-data-from-datetime-select-into-a-datet)

You can scroll down past the accepted answer to find some example methods. I don't have a Rails console in front of me to try, but I would try time_min = DateTime.new(params[:timeMin]). Rails certainly converts this hash to a date when you save it into a DB column that represents a date. If you wanted to make Rails do it all, you could save both as dates to a temporary table just to get DateTime objects out of it. You could then overwrite them with every new search.