# Ruby migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

on my web app I have a day, month ,year drop down boxes. I have a temporary render in my controller to see what is being sent into the database so I know what to migrate. however the day, month, year fields are sending in the below. But Rails generate model doesn't like the brackets. How do you over come this? Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
"date(3i)"=>"18", "date(2i)"=>"4", "date(1i)"=>"2014"


def change
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.text :title
  t.text :requester
  t.text :requester_email
  t.text :customer
  t.text :contact
  t.text :customer_email
  t.text :customer_phone
  t.string :type_of_change
  t.string :date(3i)

  t.timestamps
```

Comment: what do you mean "dont like the brakets", and what is `3i,2i,1i` in the example.

Comment: ok so there are 3 drop down boxes day/month/year the day box send date(3i)=>18 to the db I don't know where the 3i bit generates from.

Comment: when I do rails generate model Post date(3i):string it doesn't like the brackets.

Comment: please provide the failed code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073756/where-is-the-rails-method-that-converts-data-from-datetime-select-into-a-datet
That should tell you

Comment: There is no failed code. When I look at the information from my drop down boxes and how they are sent into the DB they are as above. However I cannot generate a model for it as it doesn't like the brackets.

Comment: posted the migration file with said (3i)

Comment: I mean provide the migration code, which throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

That should just be a field called date, of type date.

the `(3i)` business is down to rails' multiparameter assignment system. You have a single value in the model (a date) but the UI to manipulate them breaks it down into year/month/day.

Each of the year/month/day parameters pertains to the date and the suffix indicates which parameter is which. When parameters such as

```
"date(3i)"=>"18", "date(2i)"=>"4", "date(1i)"=>"2014"
```

are assigned to a date attribute, rails knows to use `Date::civil` to make the date. the (1i) suffix tells rails to typecast '2014' to an integer and use it as the first parameter to `Date::civil` and so on

Comment: ok so what do I type when I run rails generate model Post xxxx to allow for this?

Comment: date:date would handle that

Comment: ok i seem to get this 1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [18, 4, 2014] to date (undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass)]