# Time in Rails console, MySQL and application.rb is correct, but wrong in timestamp

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

Here's my output in console:

```
mysql> select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
+---------------------+
| CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |
+---------------------+
| 2012-04-14 16:35:57 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
VNMB:qhuen VictorNg$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.1)
1.8.7 :001 > Time.now
 => Sat Apr 14 16:36:28 +0800 2012 
1.8.7 :002 > Time.zone.now
 => Sat, 14 Apr 2012 16:36:31 MYT +08:00 
1.8.7 :003 >
```

and in my `application.rb` it is set:

```
config.time_zone = 'Kuala Lumpur'
```

But when my rails model is touched, the `updated_at` column shows:

```
2012-04-14 08:36:21
```

What else do I need to do to correct this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be misunderstanding what time formats Rails uses in various places. A question I've answered in the past might help:

[Why doesn't `config.time_zone` seem to do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073917/why-doesnt-config-time-zone-seem-to-do-anything/5074193#5074193)

If you want your local timezone used in the actual database records you can set config.active_record.default_timezone = :local in your application.rb (assuming Rails3)

Comment: Thanks. It's clearer now. How do I set back to the timestamp that I wanted?

Comment: If you want your local timezone used in the actual database records you can set `config.active_record.default_timezone = :local` in your `application.rb` (assuming Rails3)

Comment: Works like charm. Would you mind to include that in your answer, so that I can mark it as answer? Many thanks.