# Invalid argument to TimeZone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make my users Time zone be the current Time zone of my application so everything they interact will be by it. I run into an `ArgumentError` for my method inside of my ApplicationController though.

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :set_user_time_zone

private

def set_user_time_zone
  if signed_in?
   Time.zone = Time.now.in_time_zone(current_user.time_zone)
  end
end
```

Notes: current_user is a [Devise Helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) and my User model as a `:time_zone` column.

Than the error:

```
invalid argument to TimeZone[]: Mon, 20 Aug 2012 13:16:20 JST +09:00
```

I don't know where to go from here. Any ideas on how to correct this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
class Price
  attr_accessible :date
  def self.today
    where(:date => Date.today)
  end
end
```

If my method does:

```
def set_user_time_zone
  if signed_in?
    Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
  end
end
```

The problem I have my times are like this:

```
 Time.now = US EAST- 2012-08-22 21:17:03 -0400 
 Time.zone = TOKYO - (GMT+09:00) Tokyo 
 Time.zone.now 2012-08-23 10:17:03 +0900
```

Which means all of my `Date` methods go by

`Time.now = US EAST- 2012-08-22 21:17:03 -0400`

when it should be

```
Time.zone.now 2012-08-23 10:17:03 +0900
```

How can I get it to the latter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Time.now.in_time_zone(current_user.time_zone)` returns instance of `TimeWithZone` class, but
`Time#zone=` expects to get something that can be converted to `TimeZone`.

Assuming you store `TimeZone` identifiers in your `:time_zone` column (“Eastern Time (US & Canada)”, "Hawaii", etc.) you can simply do

```
Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
```

Comment: OK so I do that but if I write a method using `Date.today` it won't go by the current user's time zone but the default one `("Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`. My code above was an attempt at trying to correct this behavior. I'll show my code of a method I have called `today` that does what I described.

Comment: I also explained everything else.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean and basicly ... you can't do this (or at least shouldn't). Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5074193/1155892) answer 
I would recommend you use UTC everywhere on server side and user zone only in views and helpers.

Comment: User zone only in views and helpers?

Comment: Yes, keep time in database in UTC - this is rails default and times saved via ActiveRecord will be automatically converted from user zone to UTC. In views convert it back to user's zone so he will see his local time.

Answer (score 3):

[Time#zone=](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/Time/zone=/class) method accepts only these params:

> - A Rails TimeZone object.
> - An identifier for a Rails TimeZone object (e.g., “Eastern Time (US &
>   Canada)”, -5.hours).
> - A TZInfo::Timezone object.
> - An identifier for a TZInfo::Timezone object (e.g.,
>   “America/New_York”).

So you should pass something from this list

Comment: +1 I have used the second option ("An identifier for a Rails TimeZone object") in projects with no problems.