# Rails time is always a day behind when deployed on my server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, date

I have a calendar and when a user clicks on a day, i'm passing a javascript time variable to my rails controller via ajax.

This works fine locally, but when deployed on my server, the date seems to be a day behind the day that i clicked.

When i initially load the page with the calendar, it shows the correct day and i'm using: `day = Time.now.to_date.to_s(:db)`

When a user clicks a day in the calendar, it takes this js statement:

```
start_date: Math.floor(new Date(date).getTime()/1000)
```

which translates to this:

```
1362549600
```

and passes it ajaxilly into this rails controller method:

```
start_date = Time.at(params[:start_date].to_i).to_date.to_s(:db)
logger.info "start_date = #{start_date}"
logger.info "time = #{Time.at(params[:start_date].to_i).to_datetime.to_s(:db)}"
```

The logger output is:

```
start_date = 2013-03-05
time = 2013-03-05 22:00:00
```

I have my timezone set in config/application.rb:

```
config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Am i using an incorrect way to pass the date from js to rails?

**EDIT**

By the way in my javascript snippet, `date` is initally `Wed Feb 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)`

Another thing i just checked is my server time which is in PDT, while i physically sit in central time.

```
$ date
Tue Mar 19 16:51:52 PDT 2013
```

I also see that when running my app locally, my logger output is:

```
start_date = 2013-03-06
time = 2013-03-06 00:00:00
```

which is the difference between yesterday and today. I'm not sure what i should change to fix this.

Comment: Not sure what you're passing in the JS date() function, but did you set the time correctly on your computer as well, as javascript will use the local computers time unless the date variable comes from the serverside somehow ?

Comment: See my edit. I'm not sure if `date` comes from the user browser or the server. I'm using the fullcalendar jquery plugin.

Comment: Then it's probably a javascript date, which uses the local computers time. Did you set that correctly? Also, you're dividing and rounding down the date, are you sure that does'nt substract enough to make your date off by a day ?

Comment: I'm sure my computers clock is set right. It's set to my local time. Basically i don't care about time in my function. I'm only after the day that the user clicks.

Comment: Basically i'm just after the date (ignoring time) that the user clicked so that i can run a query that gets all the timeslots for the day the user clicked.

Comment: You might want to check the servers time - in irb try `Time.at(1362549600).utc_offset` this will let you know if the server is really in the right timezone.  I suspect it is actually in UTC-2 (wherever that is :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Time.at` will use the server system time, as will all the Date and Time functions in ruby.

The `config.time_zone` is really only used for date conversions when storing dates in the database (read or write). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5074193/10427) for some more on that.

I think if you run `irb` on the server and try `Time.at(1362549600).utc_offset / 60 / 60` you will not get the expected timezone offset of -6 hours but rather the -2 that you seem to be getting.

Comment: Ahh your link helped me out. All i needed to do was call `Time.zone.at....` and it now works.