# Converting System Date to Local Date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Model with this scope:

```
scope :next_week, lambda { where("date > (?) and date <= (?)", Date.today, Date.today + 1.weeks ) }
```

However, it changes the date too early for me, as I want the app's time as (and the server is on UTC):

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

I've seen posts on using `in_time_zone` to convert Time.now to the config time.

[Why doesn't `config.time_zone` seem to do anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073917/why-doesnt-config-time-zone-seem-to-do-anything)

Is there anything like that for dates?  Or could someone recommend an approach to adjusting my date queries to calculate `Date.today` to the local date?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `Time.current.to_date` instead of `Date.today`

Answer (score 2):

Because Date does not take into account timezones at all you'll need to use the `#to_time_in_current_zone` method that Rails adds to the Ruby `Date` object.

From the Docs:

```
Converts Date to a TimeWithZone in the current zone if Time.zone or Time.zone_default is set, otherwise converts Date to a Time via #to_time
```

Usage looks like this:

```
Date.today
# => Mon, 06 May 2013 

Date.today.to_time_in_current_zone
# => Mon, 06 May 2013 00:00:00 CDT -05:00
```

There is a fantastic blog post over at Elabs on [Working with time zones in Ruby on Rails](http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails) that gives more great information on the subject.

Comment: Thank you Dan.  I tried `Date.today.to_time_in_current_zone`, but it came back with `Tue, 07 May 2013 00:00:00 EDT -04:00` even though it is still on May 6th in EST.  The info on the linked page was good, but there is also a discussion in the comments that alludes to `Date.today.to_time_in_current_zone` not changing the day as expected.