# ruby on rails server not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tzinfo

Hi, when I try to run `rails server`, it just exits and displays the message below:

```
C:\rails_project\first_app>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.0 application starting in development on http0 0 0 0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0 0 0 0). Consider using 127.0
.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.1.0/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:1
99:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': No timezone data source could be f
ound. To resolve this, either install TZInfo::Data (e.g. by running `gem install
 tzinfo-data`) or specify a zoneinfo directory using `TZInfo::DataSource.set(:zo
neinfo, zoneinfo_path)`. (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
```

Could somebody let me know what i am missing?

Comment: did you run `bundle install` to install all needed gems? maybe `gem install tzinfo-data` needs to be done manually on windows?

Comment: DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.2.2
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.3.2
Using thread_safe 0.3.3

Comment: Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.1.0
Using activemodel 4.1.0
Using arel 5.0.0
Using activerecord 4.1.0
Using bundler 1.6.1
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.0.2
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.0
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.9.2
Using jbuilder 2.0.6
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.1.3
Using rails 4.1.0
Using rdoc 4.1.1
Using sass 3.2.19
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.0

Comment: Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using turbolinks 2.2.2
Using uglifier 2.5.0
Your bundle is updated!

C:\rails_project\first_app>

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. i just removed my previous installation of ruby on rails and reinstalled it works now.

Comment: solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191982/tzinfo-data-issue-when-starting-new-rails-project

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if you're still with that problem, i was struggling with the same issue, until after a couple weeks i finally solved it. that is a problem with x64 machines.

just go to your gemfile and search for `gem 'tzinfo-data'`

then in the array add this `:x64_mingw`

it must look like this

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
```

then save, do `bundle update` and then `bundle install`, and luckyly your rails server will start.

Comment: Yes!  You're the man!  I missed the `bundle update` and `bundle install` at first, which are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need:

```
gem install tzinfo
```

I have tzinfo 1.1.0 installed on my machine.

Another package you might need is:

```
gem install tzinfo-data
```

Be sure to add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', '1.2014.5'
```

Comment: i have tzinfo installed and did bundle update and bundle install

Comment: It works if you add to your Gemfile:

`gem 'tzinfo-data', '1.2014.5'`

But if you want future updates you should try with: 


`gem 'tzinfo-data'`

Comment: solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191982/tzinfo-data-issue-when-starting-new-rails-project

Answer (score 1):

FYI the error you're getting is probably down to the use of [`config.time_zone`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073917/why-doesnt-config-time-zone-seem-to-do-anything) in your app. The error is saying that to interpret the correct timezone, it needs to use the `tzinfo` dependency

Comment: solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191982/tzinfo-data-issue-when-starting-new-rails-project