# tzinfo-data issue when starting new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Encountered TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound issue when starting new rails project even though entry in Gemfile

When I start a new rails project, below error encountered:
C:>rails new demo2 
create
    create README.md
    create Rakefile
    create .ruby-version
    create config.ru
    create .gitignore
    create Gemfile
    run git init from "."
    create package.json
    create app
    create app/assets/config/manifest.js
    create app/assets/javascripts/application.js
    create app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
    create app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
    create app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
    create app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
    create app/controllers/application_controller.rb
    create app/helpers/application_helper.rb
    create app/jobs/application_job.rb
    create app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
    create app/models/application_record.rb
    create app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
    create app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
    create app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
    create app/assets/images/.keep
    create app/assets/javascripts/channels
    create app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
    create app/controllers/concerns/.keep
    create app/models/concerns/.keep
    create bin
    create bin/bundle
    create bin/rails
    create bin/rake
    create bin/setup
    create bin/update
    create bin/yarn
    create config
    create config/routes.rb
    create config/application.rb
    create config/environment.rb
    create config/cable.yml
    create config/puma.rb
    create config/storage.yml
    create config/environments
    create config/environments/development.rb
    create config/environments/production.rb
    create config/environments/test.rb
    create config/initializers
    create config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
    create config/initializers/assets.rb
    create config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
    create config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
    create config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
    create config/initializers/cors.rb
    create config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
    create config/initializers/inflections.rb
    create config/initializers/mime_types.rb
    create config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb
    create config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
    create config/locales
    create config/locales/en.yml
    create config/master.key
    append .gitignore
    create config/boot.rb
    create config/database.yml
    create db
    create db/seeds.rb
    create lib
    create lib/tasks
    create lib/tasks/.keep
    create lib/assets
    create lib/assets/.keep
    create log
    create log/.keep
    create public
    create public/404.html
    create public/422.html
    create public/500.html
    create public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
    create public/apple-touch-icon.png
    create public/favicon.ico
    create public/robots.txt
    create tmp
    create tmp/.keep
    create tmp/cache
    create tmp/cache/assets
    create vendor
    create vendor/.keep
    create test/fixtures
    create test/fixtures/.keep
    create test/fixtures/files
    create test/fixtures/files/.keep
    create test/controllers
    create test/controllers/.keep
    create test/mailers
    create test/mailers/.keep
    create test/models
    create test/models/.keep
    create test/helpers
    create test/helpers/.keep
    create test/integration
    create test/integration/.keep
    create test/test_helper.rb
    create test/system
    create test/system/.keep
    create test/application_system_test_case.rb
    create storage
    create storage/.keep
    create tmp/storage
    create tmp/storage/.keep
    remove config/initializers/cors.rb
    remove config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb
    run bundle install
    The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java.
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
    Resolving dependencies...
    Unable to find a spec satisfying tzinfo-data (>= 0) in the set. Perhaps the lockfile is corrupted?

I follow as suggested above:
bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java

Then:
bundle install

All seems well.

When I try to start the rails server, encountered below error:
C:\demo2>rails server
`=> Booting Puma`
`=> Rails 5.2.2 application starting in development`
`=> Run rails server -h for more startup options`
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
 57: from bin/rails:4:in ' 
 56: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in require'
 55: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in load_dependency' 
 54: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in block in require'
 53: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in require' 
    52: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    51: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in register'
    50: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    49: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in require'
    48: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in '
    47: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in invoke
    46: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in perform'
    45: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in dispatch
    44: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in invoke_command'
    43: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in run
    42: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in perform'
    41: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in tap'
    40: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in block in perform'
    39: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in start' 
    38: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in log_to_stdout'
    37: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in wrapped_app' 
    36: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in app'
    35: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in app' 
    34: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in build_app_and_options_from_config'
    33: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in parse_file'
    32: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in new_from_string'
    31: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in eval' 
    30: from config.ru:in'
    29: from config.ru:in new' 
    28: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in initialize'
    27: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in instance_eval' 
    26: from config.ru:3:in block in '
    25: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in require_relative' 
    24: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in require'
    23: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in load_dependency' 
    22: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in block in require'
    21: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in require'
    20: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    19: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in register'
    18: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    17: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in require' 
    16: from C:/demo2/config/environment.rb:5:in '
    15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in initialize!' 
    14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in run_initializers'
    13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in tsort_each' 
    12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in tsort_each'
    11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in each_strongly_connected_component' 
    10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in call'
    9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in each' 
    8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in each_strongly_connected_component_from' 
    6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in block in tsort_each' 
    4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in block in run_initializers'
    3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in run' 
    2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in instance_exec'
    1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:36:in block in ' C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/railtie.rb:39:in rescue in block in class:Railtie': tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)

Have checked the Gemfile, entry is there
    gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

Environment:
    Windows 10 64-bit
    ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x64-mingw32]
    Rails 5.2.2

Gemfile:
`source 'https://rubygems.org'`
`git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }`

`ruby '2.5.3'`

`# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'`
`gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'`
`# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record`
`gem 'sqlite3'`
`# Use Puma as the app server`
`gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'`
`# Use SCSS for stylesheets`
`gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'`
`# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets`
`gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'`
`# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes`
`gem 'duktape'`
`# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views`
`gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'`
`# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks`
`gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'`
`# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder`
`gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'`
`# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production`
`# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'`
`# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password`
`# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'`

`# Use ActiveStorage variant`
`# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'`

`# Use Capistrano for deployment`
`# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development`

`# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb`
`gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false`

`group :development, :test do`
  `# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console`
  `gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]`
`end`

`group :development do`
  `# Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.`
  `gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'`
`end`

`group :test do`
  `# Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver`
  `gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'`
  `gem 'selenium-webdriver'`
  `# Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome`
  `gem 'chromedriver-helper'`
`end`

`# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem`
`gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]`

Comment: "All seems well." okay.... whats the question then?

Comment: Was trying to figure out what was stopping my post. Have edited to complete the issue.

Comment: post your Gemfile.

Comment: Gemfile posted.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Managed to resolved the issue.

Steps:
1. Remove ", platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]" in Gemfile for "gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]"
2. Run gem uninstall tzinfo-data
3. Run bundle install

After reinstalling back tzinfo-data, the rails server is able to start up.

Thank you for suggestions and effort to try and help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution! :)

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: Thank you so much! Really so many magic in Rails on Windows

Comment: Seems to work, thanks. Now the real question: if it is only linked to the use of Windows, why this issue is not documented on [the official Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) ?

Answer (score 4):

Use

> gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2019', '>= 1.2019.2'

in your gemfile, as per [tzinfo-data gem page](https://rubygems.org/gems/tzinfo-data)

Don't forget to run bundle install after it

Answer (score 3):

It's not a real solution, but using rails on windows makes me so crazy when i tried to install it.
Try AWS C9 or another cloud development platform if you are on windows, it changes life...