# I don't know why I cannot get bundle install to operate properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, bundle-install

I have a project that uses Ruby and for an unknown reason, I cannot identify why my ruby program will not start in this particular package. Please pardon the long code. I attempted several improvised solutions, but I did them with little knowledge of the matter.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\[God, please allow this to work]\react-evernote-guided-project>cd backend

D:\[God, please allow this to work]\react-evernote-guided-project\backend>gem update --system
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-3.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rubygems-update-3.1.4
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.1.4
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-update-3.1.4
Installing darkfish documentation for rubygems-update-3.1.4
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 56 seconds
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-3.1.4
Done installing documentation for rubygems-update after 0 seconds
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `version' for nil:NilClass

D:\[God, please allow this to work]\react-evernote-guided-project\backend>rails server
Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

bundle install is not working no matter what I change.

Comment: What you show does not help in finding a solution. Have you added some new gem to your Gemfile file recently ? At what point the app started failing ?

Comment: Holy Cow!! Maxence, thank you so much for responding! TBH I don't remember all of the steps that I took to resolve this issue. It was an arduous task, and I was doing everything in my power to resolve it. All I can tell you is that I have not moved along with this project since bringing it to the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: I am not sure `gem update --system` would have any effect. I remember having problems with some gems back in the time I was developping with Windows. Maybe this thread can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54191982/tzinfo-data-issue-when-starting-new-rails-project